Read a .nc file and get variables at certain locations
I have two data files. One of them contains locations with certain spots.
data_locs <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2000, 2001, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1995),
  Month = c(1, 1, 2, 9, 9, 9),
  Day = c(24, 22, 4, 9, 21, 27),
  Long = c(11.3667, 11.6167, -0.2833, -8.9848, -8.9833, -9.3048),
  Lat = c(57.6833, 57.5500, 60.0000, 42.2412, 42.2428, 41.9963),
  Depth = c(68, 29, 141, 99, 99, 170)
)

And on the other side I have a .nc file with data from Copernicus with some variables: temperature, salinity, ocean mix layer thickness. I downloaded an example from Copernicus with reduced spatial and temporal extents that can be downloaded from my github.
What I want to do is extract the values of the raster matching the date (year/month/day), location and depth the get the projected values of the variables. However, all examples I can find online are using ncvar_get to get grided values for latitude, longitude, etc. and then looking for closes locations instead of using the capabilities of the rasters.
It may be a problem of concept but isn't it better to use the projected? How do I extract the values of the locations in data_locs?

Which data from that site do you have in your .nc file? The "Data Access" button leads me to more choices, and some of those appear to be a set of daily 1Gb files...

I used a Python code to download the data, an example with reduced temporal and spatial extents can be found in my github https://github.com/amencia/amencia_public/blob/main/cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m_multi-vars_8.00W-5.00W_45.00N-47.00N_0.49-5727.92m_2018-08-12-2018-08-17.nc

What are "projected values of the variables" and "the capabilities of the rasters"? Your ncdf has variables indexed by dimensions of lat, long, depth and time, your data frame has those measures in possible continuous values, so at some point you have to match those up with the netcdf dimensions, and choosing the nearest values in the data dimensions is a justifiably good way to do this...

I thought that a raster was like a layer and that it had exact values on a grid (the indexed values you are talking about) and then some kind of projected values in case you specify a point in the layer that does not belong to the grid. I now think (now I see that this actually works by interpolating when you use functions like extract / st_extract). Is it possible to use st_extract / extract to get the values of the variable in those locations, time and depth?

I would use {terra} package for it. A kind of workflow might be:
I have changed your data.frame a bit to have a date in the same period as the layers in provided .nc file, the same applies to coordinates (they are within extend of .nc. I have added date variable in the same format as is stored in .nc file (read in by terra:rast() function).
data_locs <- data.frame(
  Year = c("2018", "2000", "2001"),
  Month = c("08", "01", "01"),
  Day = c("12", "24", "22"),
  Long = c(-6, -5, -7),
  Lat = c(45, 46, 47),
  Depth = c(68, 29, 141)
) |>
  dplyr::mutate(date = as.POSIXct(paste0(Year, "-", Month, "-", Day), tz="UTC"))

Let's read the .nc file:
r <- terra::rast("~/Downloads/cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m_multi-vars_8.00W-5.00W_45.00N-47.00N_0.49-5727.92m_2018-08-12-2018-08-17.nc")
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 25, 37, 618  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : -8.041667, -4.958333, 44.95833, 47.04167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> sources     : cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m_multi-vars_8.00W-5.00W_45.00N-47.00N_0.49-5727.92m_2018-08-12-2018-08-17.nc:bottomT  (6 layers) 
#>               cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m_multi-vars_8.00W-5.00W_45.00N-47.00N_0.49-5727.92m_2018-08-12-2018-08-17.nc:mlotst  (6 layers) 
#>               cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m_multi-vars_8.00W-5.00W_45.00N-47.00N_0.49-5727.92m_2018-08-12-2018-08-17.nc:thetao  (300 layers) 
#>               ... and 2 more sources
#> varnames    : bottomT (Sea floor potential temperature) 
#>               mlotst (Density ocean mixed layer thickness) 
#>               thetao (Temperature) 
#>               ...
#> names       : bottomT_1, bottomT_2, bottomT_3, bottomT_4, bottomT_5, bottomT_6, ... 
#> unit        : degrees_C, degrees_C, degrees_C, degrees_C, degrees_C, degrees_C, ... 
#> time        : 2018-08-12 to 2018-08-17 UTC

618 layers spread by variables, depth and time.
terra::time(r)[1:10]
#>  [1] "2018-08-12 UTC" "2018-08-13 UTC" "2018-08-14 UTC" "2018-08-15 UTC"
#>  [5] "2018-08-16 UTC" "2018-08-17 UTC" "2018-08-12 UTC" "2018-08-13 UTC"
#>  [9] "2018-08-14 UTC" "2018-08-15 UTC"

Let's convert the data frame to terra vect() object (I have assumed the CRS of .nc and your data.frame are the same, if they are different, use terra::project() function to mach them):
v <- terra::vect(data_locs, geom =c("Long", "Lat"), crs = terra::crs(r))

Now we have to: limit the rasters only to those which match the date, the depth and extract the values. As the depth in the layers doesn't match those given in data.frame either you would stick to neighbors, either you can use terra::approximate() function to estimate the values on dept 68 with surrounding layers.
r[[which(terra::time(r) == v[1, ]$date)]] |>
  terra::subset(subset = "thetao_depth=65.807266_1") |>
  terra::extract(v)
#>   ID thetao_depth=65.807266_1
#> 1  1                 12.42308
#> 2  2                 12.32127
#> 3  3                 12.36888

The values 12.423, 12.321 and 12.368 corresponds to 3 points from data.frame from depth = 65.8 (close to requested 68) for potential water temperature.
To get names of all layers use terra:names(r) and grepl() for requested variable/depth.
And the plot on the end because spatial analysis without plot is not an analysis :).
r[[which(terra::time(r) == v[1, ]$date)]] |>
  terra::subset(subset = "thetao_depth=65.807266_1") |>
  terra::plot()


Created on 2024-11-21 with reprex v2.1.1.9000
